# Visual Studio 2017 crash when publishing web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, web-publishing

After updating my Visual studio to version 15.8.1 it has started to crash every time I try to publish a web application.

I try to use web deploy and fileSystem options, both crash. Changing the settings like unchecking delete unused files as no effect. Giving full permissions to the destination folder has no effect either.

Comment: Are there any errors given in the outpiut window before crashing?

Comment: No, just hangs and start collecting crash data.

Comment: Can you post the crash data?

Comment: I don't know were it stores. Takes several minutes to collect and send to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the publish profile solved the issue. Something must have changed for pubxml file.